# Bind or "connect" QUdpSocket to remote host and port?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp, qt5

I would like to "connect" QUdpSocket to a remote host-port, but fail to do so. Is it possible?

The scenario I would like to implement is the following:

1) The server binds to localhost/port:

```
// On server side, let server IP be "192.168.0.235"
serverUdpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost), 44444);
... // check if connection is ok, etc
serverUdpSocket->write(someByteArray);
```

2) The client reads data from server, I tried:

```
// bind fails with SocketAddressNotAvailableError
udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress("192.168.0.235"), 44444);
```

and this way:

```
udpSocket->connectToHost(QHostAddress("192.168.0.235"), 44444, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
// State becomes "Connected", but I don't get any data and `readyRead()`
// is never emitted, though I connected to it.
```

but it doesn't work.

I know that UDP is a connectionless protocol. A also managed to do it vice versa - bind to local host and send data to this host from another. But I'm interested in this way of doing it, as remote host might be a server providing audio stream, that I want to read with my code.

In examples and tutorials I only see binding to local port and reading data from it. No examples with binding to remote host-port provided.

Comment: If you connect() your socket to 192.168.0.235 port 4444, you'll only be able to receive packets from that address/port. But which is your local UDP port, that you send packets to ?

Comment: @nos I'm perfectly fine with receiving packets from that address/port, as I expect data from it. Should it bother me, am I'm missing something? The local UDP port is the same - 44444. So I kind of expect to send packets to local UDP port on one host and some other host might connect to it to the same port and receive the data.

Comment: No, I'm just asking 2 things. 1. Are you sending FROM 192.168.0.235 port 44444, TO your server(your program here) ? 2. What is the address (IP address and port number) of your program? You say your bind() fails, so which port did you bind() your program to , did you bind it to any port at all ?

Comment: @nos please see the updated question

Answer (score 4):

`bind()` binds a socket to a local address. `connect()` connects a socket to a remote address. Usually servers bind and clients connect.

Comment: Does your answer states that what I asked is impossible?

Comment: No, it states that the way you're doing it is wrong. You don't need to bind the client.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But if that is wrong, what is the right way to achieve what I need and explained in the question? I don't see how the "correct" way of doing this will help me out.

Comment: The correct way is to call `connect(),` as in all TCP clients. This information is already contained in my answer.